# Code is Working Properly in NetBeans but not in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, exception, netbeans, ide

I have tried the following jsp file in both IDEs. It is working good in NetBeans, but it is not working in Eclipse. The program is to get the time from a NTP server.

Code is as follows

```
 <%-- 
Document   : GetNTP
Created on : May 21, 2013, 2:21:29 PM
Author     : Maximin
--%>
<%@page import="java.net.InetAddress"%>
<%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
<%@page import ="java.util.Date"%>

<%@page import="org.apache.commons.net.ntp.NTPUDPClient"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.net.ntp.TimeInfo"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><%
    String TIME_SERVER = "time.nist.gov";
    NTPUDPClient timeClient = new NTPUDPClient();
    InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(TIME_SERVER);
    TimeInfo timeInfo = timeClient.getTime(inetAddress);
    long returnTime = timeInfo.getReturnTime();
    Date time = new Date(returnTime);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            out.println(sdf.format(time));
    %></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

When i run this in eclipse I get as

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 17 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. org.apache.commons.net.ntp.NTPUDPClient resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: 18 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. org.apache.commons.net.ntp.TimeInfo resolves to a package

 An error occurred at line: 18 in the jsp file: /GetTime.jsp
NTPUDPClient cannot be resolved to a type
15: <body>
16: <h1><%
17:         String TIME_SERVER = "time.nist.gov";
18:         NTPUDPClient timeClient = new NTPUDPClient();
19:         InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(TIME_SERVER);
20:         TimeInfo timeInfo = timeClient.getTime(inetAddress);
21:         long returnTime = timeInfo.getReturnTime();
```

Why is it so?

What should I do to make it run on Eclipse?

Comment: Might be classpath issue check your build path of the project.

Comment: @Karthikeyan When I ran the same content as j2se level it worked. I have added the jar properly.

Comment: That's the runtime complaining, not Eclipse.  Have you double checked those package/type messages to make absolutely sure that's not true in your commons jars?

Comment: @nitind yes. I did. The jar is still in the path.

Comment: Is it also marked for deployment on the Deployment Assembly property page?

Comment: @nitind What is that? How should I do that?

Comment: Right click on your project and choose Properties (it's at the bottom...probably).  Deployment Assembly is one of the pages.  If the jar with the NTP classes is not in WebContent/WEB-INF/lib or otherwise on the server, make sure it is on this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked for me:

"Right click on your project and choose Properties (it's at the bottom...probably). Deployment Assembly is one of the pages. If the jar with the NTP classes is not in WebContent/WEB-INF/lib or otherwise on the server, make sure it is on this page."

Answered by [nitind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27905/nitind)